# How to change DisplayField text in ExtJs 3.0?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to change 'Labelxx' to 'New Label' in a DisplayField. How can I do this? Below is my code:

```
MyFormUi = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
    title: 'Rates ',
    id: 'id_form',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Labelxx',
            anchor: '100%',
            name: 'name_lb',
            ref: 'localCurrencylbl',
            id: 'id_lb'
        }];
        MyFormUi.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change DisplayField `text`:

```
Ext.getCmp('id_lb').setValue('New text');
```

To change the `fieldLabel`:

```
Ext.getCmp('id_lb').setFieldLabel('New Label');
```

**Note:** It is not recommended to work with id's tho.

Answer (score 2):

To change the fieldLabel in ExtJs 3.X:

```
Ext.getCmp('id_lb').label.update("Dynamically changed text");
```

Answer (score 0):

setValue will change the value of displayfield. It will not change the fieldLabel.

Comment: Read the question and your answer should be a comment.

Comment: I did read it. There was not an option to add comment. At least not for my login. Neither in your answer nor in question. Still I am not seeing comment option to add comment in yours except mine.

And Duleep asked to change fieldLabel as Labelxx is a field label in his code not the value which you have suggested previously with setValue.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display

Check out link, it doesn't have setFieldLabel as a method to xtype:'displayfield'. I even tried in my local environment neither it works nor FireBug suggests it as one of the method.

Comment: Alright. `setFieldLabel` is available since Ext 4.1.0 and is indeed not related to this question. I guess you can do it in Ext3 something like this: `displayfield.fieldLabel = 'labelxx';`